# Why this part need forced type conversion

Tags: java, type-conversion

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {

        if (otherObject instanceof Person) {
            Person otherPerson = (Person) otherObject;

            if (this.age == otherPerson.age) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

This is a code, I find at a book.
I don't konw, why `Person otherPerson = (Person) otherObject;` need forced type conversion.

After trying many situations, I think may it is no need?

Comment: That is called casting, so you can access its own attributs/methods

Comment: Because `equals` expects an `Object` as a parameter so, syntactically speaking, you could be passing it any kind of object. You can try: `var p = new Person("joe", 30); System.out.println(p.equals("clearly not a person"));`